# Geometric mean filter for denoising image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, geometric-mean

I am new to MATLAB. I don't know how to use geometric mean filter for filtering noisy image. For arithmetic mean filter I use this:

```
H = fspecial('average',5);
a = imfilter(a, H);
```

Is there any similar way for geometric mean filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. I suggest reading both the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) about geometric mean as well as [this blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/07/07/nonlinear-operations-using-imfilter/) by Steve Eddins who works at The Mathworks.

To borrow Steve's explanation (and whole code/example actually):

> The local geometric mean filter multiplies together all the pixel
>   values in the neighborhood and then takes the N-th root, where N is
>   the number of pixels in the neighborhood.

So in terms of Matlab code, with `h` being the kernel filled with ones having size of the neighborhood you use to compute the average and `I` being your image:

```
geo_mean = imfilter(log(I), h, 'replicate');
geo_mean = exp(geo_mean);
geo_mean = geo_mean .^ (1/numel(h));
```

Hope that helps!